# Vba code to return header and row data based on input box value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. Each sheet has columns A to AO and the number of rows on each sheet varies. Each sheet is not in arrays. I am trying to write vba to open an input box, then search through the workbook (all sheets) for a value, or multiple values (separated by comma). I want the code to open a new workbook, copy the headers (this can be from any sheet of the original as all are the same) to rows 1 and 2 of the new workbook\sheet (the headers span two rows). Then I want all row data from any row in which a search value is found to be populated, starting in row 3,and then in the next free row underneath for each instance. Lastly, I want the colours and formatting of the original workbook to also be copied across. My attempts to date have been an utter fail, but to show I have attempted this, I include my workings below. This errors on search value I will be eternally grateful for a working solution!

```
Sub SearchForValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim outputRow As Long
    Dim outputCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim outputBook As Workbook
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim headerRange As Range
    
    ' Prompt user for the search value(s)
    searchValue = InputBox("Enter the value(s) to search for (separate multiple values with comma):")
    If searchValue = "" Then Exit Sub ' User cancelled or didn't enter a value
    
    ' Create a new workbook to output the results
    Set outputBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set outputSheet = outputBook.Sheets(1)
    outputSheet.Name = "Search Results"
    
    ' Write the headers to the output sheet
    Set headerRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet x").Range("A2:AO2")
    headerRange.Copy outputSheet.Range("A1")
    Set headerRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet x").Range("A1:AO1")
    headerRange.Copy outputSheet.Range("A2")
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Search for the values in columns A to AO of the worksheet
        Set searchRange = ws.Range("A:AO")
        For Each searchValue In Split(searchValue, ",")
            Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            
            ' If the value is found, output the row data to the output workbook
            If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
                ' Write the sheet name and row number to the output sheet
                outputRow = outputSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' Move to the next free row in the output sheet
                outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, 1).Value = ws.Name
                outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, 2).Value = foundCell.Row
                
                ' Loop through each column and output the cell value and format
                outputCol = 1 ' Start outputting data in column 1
                For i = 1 To searchRange.Columns.Count
                    ws.Cells(foundCell.Row, i).Copy
                    outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, outputCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    outputSheet.Cells(outputRow, outputCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    outputCol = outputCol + 1
                Next i
            End If
        Next searchValue
    Next ws
    
    ' Auto-fit the columns on the output sheet
    outputSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    
    ' Save and close the output workbook
    outputBook.SaveAs "Search Results.xlsx"
    outputBook.Close

    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

End Sub
```

I was expecting this to complete the outlined task.

Comment: Could it be that you just need to use a different variable for the seperate values in your `Split`? So not `For Each searchValue In Split(searchValue, ",")` but something like `For Each sValue In Split(searchValue, ",")`. A few pointers: you can copy both header-rows to the new sheet in one go, there's usually not much of a point setting a range to it if you're using it once. The outputrow can be placed before the `For Each` and then adjust with a simple addition when you get into your `If Not foundCell Is Nothing`. Also can copy that entire range (all columns in `searchRange.Columns.Count`)

Comment: Thanks Notus_Panda. With your revision would sValue have to be designated as a variable, using "Dim sValue as string"?

Comment: Yes, it's always advised to declare your variables and in this case, it'd be a string since you're `searchValue` is also a string (makes sense anyway when asking for input); if need be, you can convert the separate values to something else.

Comment: Just curious, in what line the sub throw an error when you run it ?

Comment: For each SearchValue in split. The original code runs, opens the input box, then errors after the value has been entered on this line.

Comment: With searchValue amended to sValue and named as Dim sValue as, string, the code errors on sValue - not identifying it as an object or variable. Is anyone able to provide a complete working code for the outlined problem. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote `Dim sValue` which is short for `Dim sValue As Variant`. I know that we are looping through strings of a strings array, but the variable still has to be declared as a Variant. I didn't make up the rules. BTW refresh the page, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Search For Multiple Criteria in All Worksheets

- Your current error is occurring because you cannot do

  ```
   For Each searchValue In Split(searchValue, ",")
  ```
- The `For Each Next loop` needs a Variant (or Object) Control variable, a different one than the one used for the input string `searchValue` e.g.:

  ```
  Dim sValue
  For Each sValue In Split(searchValue, ",")
  Next sValue
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchForValues()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Search For Values"
    Const IB_PROMPT As String = "Enter the value(s) to search for " _
        & "(separate multiple values by comma):"
    Const DST_WB_NAME As String = "Search Results.xlsx"
    Const DST_WS_NAME As String = "Search Results"
    Const COLS As String = "A:AO"
    Const HEADER_ROWS As Long = 2
    Const INPUT_DELIMITER As String = ","
    
    ' Get input.
    
    Dim InputString As String
    InputString = InputBox(Prompt:=IB_PROMPT, Title:=PROC_TITLE)
    
    If InputString = "" Then
        MsgBox "Operation canceled!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Split input to array.
    
    Dim sArr() As String: sArr = Split(InputString, INPUT_DELIMITER)
    
    ' Clean input in array.
    
    Dim n As Long, cn As Long, sStr As String
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(sArr)
        sStr = Application.Trim(sArr(n))
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
            cn = cn + 1
            sArr(cn - 1) = sStr
        End If
    Next n
    
    If cn = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No valid values entered!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Input to dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    For n = 0 To cn - 1
        dict(sArr(n)) = Empty
    Next n
    
    ' Source Workbook
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = swb.Worksheets(1).Range(COLS).Columns.Count
    Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = HEADER_ROWS + 1
    
    ' Declare variables for the loop.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, surg As Range, sr As Long, srCount As Long
    Dim dwb As Workbook, dws As Worksheet, drg As Range, dfrg As Range
    Dim Data, c As Long, dr As Long, drCount As Long
    Dim SearchStriung As String, FirstFound As Boolean
    
    ' The Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        
        ' Reference the source used range.
        Set surg = sws.UsedRange.Columns(COLS)
        srCount = surg.Rows.Count - HEADER_ROWS
        
        If srCount > 0 Then ' data found
            
            ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
            Data = surg.Resize(srCount).Offset(HEADER_ROWS).Value
            
            For sr = 1 To srCount
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    SearchStriung = CStr(Data(sr, c))
                    ' On first match in row, exit the loop.
                    If dict.Exists(SearchStriung) Then Exit For
                Next c
                ' If not found 'c > cCount' i.e. the loop was not interrupted
                If c <= cCount Then ' match found; write to the top of the array
                    dr = dr + 1
                    drCount = drCount + 1
                    For c = 1 To cCount
                        Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
                    Next c
                'Else ' match not found; do nothing
                End If
            Next sr
            
            If dr > 0 Then ' match found
            
                ' Copy the source worksheet to a new workbook,
                ' the destination workbook, and clear all data rows except
                ' the first data row to be used to copy formatting.
                If Not FirstFound Then
                    sws.Copy
                    Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
                    Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
                    dws.Name = DST_WS_NAME
                    With dws.UsedRange
                        Set dfrg = .Rows(FirstRow)
                        dfrg.ClearContents
                        .Resize(.Rows.Count - FirstRow).Offset(FirstRow).Clear
                    End With
                    FirstFound = True
                'Else ' first match already found; do nothing
                End If
                
                ' Write the values from the top of the array to the destination.
                Set drg = dfrg.Resize(dr)
                dfrg.Copy drg.Offset(1) ' copy formats
                drg.Value = Data ' copy values
                Set dfrg = dfrg.Offset(dr) ' reset for the next iteration
                dr = 0 ' reset for the next iteration (worksheet)
            
            'Else ' no match found; do nothing
            End If
        
        'Else ' no data found; do nothing
        End If
    
    Next sws
        
    If Not FirstFound Then
        MsgBox "No matching values found!" _
            & vbLf & vbLf & "Searched for the following:" _
            & vbLf & vbLf & Join(dict.Keys, vbLf), vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    dfrg.Clear ' clear the formatting row
    
    ' Save and close the output workbook.
    
    'dwb.SaveAs DST_WB_NAME
    'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Extracted " & drCount & " row" & IIf(drCount = 1, "", "s") _
        & " of data.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008 will try this shortly.

Comment: VBasic2008 this is awesome - works perfectly. Thank you so much! One final minor query - to copy across blank cells as blank not "n/a" is it possible to achieve this in your code with an IFERROR statement - and if yes - where should this go?

Comment: Apologies. Found the issue. Just needed to change the criteria from A:O to A:AO to fit the designated range. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry for losing 26 columns. Fixed it.